# greatest interval of values of $x$ for which $2x\leq 2\sin x-\sin 2x\leq 5x$ is >$[a,b]$

Tags: calculus

> Let $x\in \left[0,3\right]$ and the greatest interval of values of $x$ for which $2x\leq 2\sin x-\sin 2x\leq 5x$ is
>
> $[a,b]$,Then find value of $\displaystyle \frac{3a}{b}$

$\bf{Attempt:}$ from $2\sin x-\sin 2x = 2\sin x-2\sin x\cos x = 2\sin x(1-\cos x)$

So $$2x\leq \sin x(1-\cos x)\leq 5x$$

$$2x\leq 2\sin x\sin^2 \frac{x}{2}\leq 5x$$

for left side , $$\sin x\sin^2 \frac{x}{2}\geq x$$

By using Inequality   $\sin x \geq x\forall x \geq 0$

so $\displaystyle \sin x\sin^2 \frac{x}{2}\geq x\sin^2 \frac{x}{2}$

could some help me to solve it, thanks

Comment: have you tried to plot your inequality?

Answer (score 2):

The squeezing as given is true for $x=0$. When $x>0$ then this squeezing is equivalent to
$$1\leq{\sin x\over x}(1-\cos x)\leq{5\over2}\ .$$ 
This does not hold for any $x>0$. The maximal interval therefore is $[0,0]$, but ${3a\over b}$ is undefined in this case.

Please at least copy your homework correctly when posting here!

Comment: Thanks Christian Blatter, I will conform it from original source.